# Loop print of 2 columns in to 1

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, pretty-print

Suppose I have an array of 2 columns. It looks like this
column1 = [1,2,3,...,830]
column2 = [a,b,c,...]

I want to have output in a print form of single columns, that includes value of both columns one by one. output form: column = [1,a,2,b ....]

I tried to do by this code,

```
dat0 = np.genfromtxt("\", delimiter = ',')
mu = dat0[:,0]
A = dat0[:,1]
print(mu,A)
R = np.arange(0,829,1)
l = len(mu)
K = np.zeros((l, 1))
txtfile = open("output_all.txt",'w')
for x in mu:
    i = 0
    K[i,0] = x
    dat0[i,1] = M
    txtfile.write(str(x))
    txtfile.write('\n')
    txtfile.write(str(M))
    txtfile.write('\n')
print K
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your code completely, is the reference to numpy really relevant for your question? What is `M`?

If you have two lists of the same lengths you can get pairs of elements using the `zip` builtin.

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for a, b in zip(A, B):
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

This will print

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a list with those elements. So an append is in order, I guess?

Comment: Append is probably clearest, if you prefer to use iteration only, you can use `[x for pair in zip(A, B) for x in pair]`

Comment: Clever, I was trying to do it that way, but didn't quite manage in a clean way :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but one method is

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3], ['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]) 
>>> new_a = []
>>> for column in range(0,a.shape[1]):           # a.shape[1] is the number of columns in a
...     for row in range(0,a.shape[1]):          # a.shape[0] is the number of rows in a
...             new_a.append(a[row][column])   
...
>>> numpy.array(new_a) 
array(['1', 'a', 'd', '2', 'b', 'e', '3', 'c', 'f'],
     dtype='|S1')
```